# ImportError in Django with FastCGI & Lighttpd

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, lighttpd

However, I am very new to django and lighttpd and have very rough idea about FastCGI. I have a django project named 'myproject' under my "server.document-root".

When I try to browse the following url:

```
http://192.168.1.198:8093/myproject.fcgi
```

I get an import error saying:

```
Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://192.168.1.198:8093/myproject.fcgi

Django Version:     1.2.4

Exception Type:     ImportError

Exception Value:    

No module named myproject.urls

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in 

import_module, line 35

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.6

Python Version:     2.6.2
```

The snippet of my "lighttpd.conf" file for configuring FastCGI is:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "192\.168\.1\.198" {                                                                      
fastcgi.server = (                                                                                     
    ".fcgi" => (                                                                                       
        "192\.168\.1\.198" => (                                                                        
            "bin-path" => "/satellite_app/webservers/lighttpd/var/www/htdocs/myproject/myproject.fcgi",
            "socket" => "/tmp/myproject.sock",                                                         
            "check-local" => "disable",                                                                
            "min-procs" => 2,                                                                          
            "max-procs" => 4,                                                                          
        )                                                                                              
    ),                                                                                                                                                                             

)                                                                                                      

alias.url = (                                                                                          
    "/media" => "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/",                        
)                                                                                                      

url.rewrite-once = (                                                                                   
    "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",                                                                            
    "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",                                                         
    "^(/.*)$" => "/myproject$1",                                                                       
  ##  "^(/.*)$" => "/myproject.fcgi$1",                                                                

)   
}
```

I am not able to identify why I am getting the "ImportError". Am I missing the import statement anywhere? If yes, kindly tell me where exactly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since I figured out the problem myself I am answering my own question hoping that it would help other newbies like me..

There was a problem with the value of `DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS`.

Setting it as :

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "myproject.settings"
```

solved my ImportError... :-)